# SpringFox/Jackson doesn't parse JSON attribute

Tags: jackson, swagger

I'm using Spring boot with springfox and having problems parsing JSON payload from Swagger UI into Java class (JSON->POJO). No errors, but the resulting Java object is missing a field (null). The top class for the class with missing attribute has Mixin to switch datatypes. That part works fine.

I can't really debug since framework does most of the parsing. The req-d attribute is displayed in  Swagger under Model Schema correctly. However, when I submit JSON payload containing same attribute, the corresp POJO's attribute is null.

Please steer me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out my issue: I was missing setter for the field in the Mixin interface. The JSON was being parsed, but the setter was missing, hence null value.